# Combo box state of labels based on the user`s choice

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a combo box with two options, and I want that the the choice in the combo box will determine the status of two labels. I mean, for example if the user chooses "1" I want him to see only the first label, and if he chooses "2" the second label will appear to. I successfully have done it but the problem is that after choosing once, this implementation is not working anymore, I mean that when a new selection is made I can't make it work

So this is my code:

```
self.comboBox.textActivated['QString'].connect(self.on_combobox_changed)
self.label_2.hide()

  

    def on_combobox_changed(self):
        if self.comboBox.currentText() == "2":
            self.label_2.show()
```

Ok, I just added a for loop like that and it seems working but I don't sure if it is a good implementation

**Edit**:

```
def on_combobox_changed(self):
    for x in range(0, 1000):
        if self.comboBox.currentText() == "2":
            self.label_2.show()
        else:
            self.label_2.hide()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: No, using a loop for that is certainly *not* a good implementation. Why are you using `textActivated` and not `currentTextChanged`? And why are you using the `[QString]` syntax? Signal signature selection is unnecessary for signals that have only one possible signature (like all signals of QComboBox). Finally, if you want to check for the text, the signal already provides it in the argument, no need to check for the `currentText()` property.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thank you for answering. Secondly, I'm really new at this Gui thing and the pyqt5, so I just did it intuitively. Finally, can I ask you to show me an example of how should It work? I didn't make it l. @musicamante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the `textActivated` signal is sent as soon as an item in the combobox is selected.

While this might seem intuitive, you have to consider the following aspects.

1. the signal is sent even if the item is already the *current* one
2. due to the above, it is also always sent whenever the user activates an item in the combo, which also happens when the user:

   - uses keyboard navigation (arrow keys, home/end, page up/down);
   - uses keyboard to search within the combo items;
   - presses enter on an editable combo;
   - clicks on an item in the popup;
3. keyboard interaction or mouse selection does *not* immediately update the contents of the view, including the `currentText()` property, as Qt needs some time to do its *stuff* (usually, updating the combo model if an editable combo has a new item that is going to be added)

Also, an important aspect to consider is that `textActivated` is a quite new feature (it was introduced in Qt 5.14 at the end of 2019, less than a year ago), and for your needs is probably not that necessary.

Finally, string comparison for index-based objects is *rarely* a good idea, and for at least two important reasons:

1. at some point, you might need to do some localization; while in your simple case it's just a string representation of a number, someday that simple "2" might become "text 2", "texto 2", "texte 2" or "testo 2".
2. UI based frameworks sometimes automatically alter the displayed text of widgets; while this is not usually the case for combobox items, Qt sometimes changes the text set for a widget in order to include *mnemonics*: text that includes an underlined letter that can be used as a keyboard accelerator and that is programmatically readable as that letter preceded by a `&`; the result is that you set the text "Save" on a button and then when you call `button.text()` you get "&Save".

So, considering the above, this is a possible implementation of what you might need (using combo item indexes instead of strings):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class ComboTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.comboBox.addItems(['Label 1', 'Label 2'])

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello, label 1!')
        layout.addWidget(self.label_1, 1, 0)

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello, label 2!')
        layout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 1)

        self.label_2.hide()

        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.showLabel)

    def showLabel(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            self.label_1.show()
            self.label_2.hide()
        elif index == 1:
            self.label_1.hide()
            self.label_2.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = ComboTest()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A final note.
Hiding widgets *before* showing their parent might be a problem. In the example above you will notice that when you select the second item and *then* the first one again, the widget will resize itself. While in this specific case it might not that big of an issue, for complex layouts that's not a good thing from the user experience perspective (users don't like when the UI changes its size unexpectedly). A possible alternative is to use a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) instead, add the labels to it with [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#addWidget), and use the combo index to call its [`setCurrentIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop).

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class ComboTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.comboBox.addItems(['Label 1', 'Label 2'])

        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello, label 1!')
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.label_1)

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello, label 2!')
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.label_2)

        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = ComboTest()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your detailed answer. Learned a lot from that answer. appreciate it.